# Why am I getting "Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)" runtime error in c?

Tags: c, runtime, abort

I was trying to submit a solution to a problem on Geek4geeks website. I've checked the solution it seems correct and does not show runtime errors on codeblocks, however it shows the Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT) runtime error on the website. please help me understand what is going wrong here.

this is my code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int greatestVol(int* volumes, int k);

int volumeCal(int* array, int N);

int main()
{
    int T, test, N, array[100], i=0;

    scanf("%d", &T);

    for(test=1;test<=T;++test)
    {
        scanf("%d", &N);
        for(i=0;i<N;++i)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", volumeCal(array, N));
    }

    return 0;
}

int greatestVol(int* volumes, int k)
{
    int i, sol=0;

    for(i=0;i<k;++i)
    {
        if(volumes[i]>sol)
        {
            sol=volumes[i];
        }
        else
            continue;
    }

    return sol;
}

int volumeCal(int* array, int N)
{
    int i, j, k=0, volumes[100], tot=0;

    for(i=0;i<N;++i)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<N;++j)
        {
            if(array[i]<array[j])
            {
                volumes[k]=array[i]*(j-i);
                ++k;
            }
            else
            {
                volumes[k]=array[j]*(j-i);
                ++k;
            }
        }
    }

    return greatestVol(volumes, k);
}
```

Comment: Do you need to reset `k=0` inside one of the nested loops? Because you didn't, you might be passing, effectively, `N * N` to function `greatestVol()` as the array length. Or, if you intended that, perhaps `volumes[100]` is too small and needs to be `volumes[10000]`

Comment: ... I guess you tested the code with only 10 elements. Always test code submitted to these sites with the full range of specs.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks man. i changed volumes length to 1000 and it worked. but i didnt quite understand why? could you answer that too?

Comment: The `volumes` length needs to be `10000` not `1000` or `100` because you increment `k` by `N` times `N` times.